# Expression in ng-include | src with string

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to make a url in ng-include|src using expression and constant string.
I'm trying below code but it's not working.

```
<aside ng-include src="{{staticPath}} + 'assets/tpl/products-feed-history.html'"></aside>
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Try `{{staticPath + 'assets/tpl/products-feed-history.html'}}`

Comment: The way you mentioned is not working.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this is to form the src string in your controller like this

```
$scope.finalSRC = $scope.staticPath + 'assets/tpl/products-feed-history.html';
```

so you can use it like this

```
<aside ng-include src="finalSRC"></aside>
```

**EDIT:**

If you really wanna do it that way, just remove the double curly braces and have it like this instead.

```
<aside ng-include src="staticPath + 'assets/tpl/products-feed-history.html'"></aside>
```

You don't need {{ }} as it evaluates expression, hence will evaluate your variable automatically

Comment: I want to evaluate URL in HTML itself. Nowhere else.